# Display login form as a table using CSS

Tags: html, css

I am totally naive in HTML/ CSS. Following is my form and I want to display that in the form of table in CSS, not HTML:

```
<div id="form">
    <form name="loginSubmit">
        <div class="inputBox">
            <b>First name:</b> <input type="text" name="Username">
        </div>
        <div class="seperator"></div>
        <div class="inputBox">
            <b>Password:</b> <input id="txtPassword" type="password" name="pwd">
        </div>
        <div class="seperator"></div>
        <b>Remember me</b> <input type="button" id="1" value="ON"
                style="color: black" onclick="toggle(this);" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: your html looks good - did you look at any basic free css tutorial?  if you try you will probably succeed.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "in the form of table in CSS, not HTML". You want this to look like a table?

Comment: Like, <b>First name:</b> <input type="text" name="Username"> in same row(in the form of rows).. I am asking this because the username is not centered with the input box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it rendered as a CSS table, you need to set `display` properties on elements reflecting the table structure. This requires at least one change to the markup, namely putting the two elements that should (presumably) constitute the last row into a container than can be made a row. Assuming the empty `div` elements are to be discarded in rendering, here’s the code:

```
<style>
#form > form { display: table }
#form > form > div { display: table-row }
#form > form > div.seperator { display: none }
#form > form > div > * { display: table-cell }
</style>
<div id="form">
    <form name="loginSubmit">
        <div class="inputBox">
            <b>First name:</b> <input type="text" name="Username">
        </div>
        <div class="seperator"></div>
        <div class="inputBox">
            <b>Password:</b> <input id="txtPassword" type="password" name="pwd">
        </div>
        <div class="seperator"></div>
        <div>
        <b>Remember me</b> <input type="button" id="1" value="ON"
                style="color: black" onclick="toggle(this);" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Using an HTML table is easier, more robust, and more structural. This homework (?) was however potentially useful in illustrating how CSS table formatting can be used in situations where HTML tables cannot be used.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest taking a look at bootstrap. It makes creating forms really easy.

Here's an example: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms

All you need to do is add this to your header:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is very simple [example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VJa5w/) based on your code. I used `display: inline-block` to format text:

```
#form > form input, #form > form b {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like the following:

```
  <form name="loginSubmit">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><b>First name:</b></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="Username"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Password:</b></td>
            <td><input id="txtPassword" type="password" name="pwd"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Remember me</b></td> 
            <td><input type="button" id="1" value="ON" style="color: black" onclick="toggle(this);" /></td>
    </tr>
     </table>       
   </form>
```

This will solve any alignment issues.

Comment: How can I do the same using CSS properties.